# Where can I find an image watermark control for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, image, watermark

Is there a good image watermark control for Delphi? It would be nice if it could receive both text and images to insert in a base photo.

I would also prefer it was free.

Comment: Slow down with the questions and focus on some quality. Check out some of my edits for examples.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any pre-packaged controls.  But watermarking is not very hard at all.  All you simply need to do is draw an image on top of another image with the use of alpha blending.  [This](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/Graphics/Algorithms.htm) site has a whole section on alpha blending in Delphi.  They provide links to graphics libraries which have implemented it.

However if you're using Delphi.NET, and can access the relevant classes in the framework, there is an easier way using only framework methods.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Graphics32](http://graphics32.org/wiki/) together with [GraphicEX](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=13&Itemid=33).

Or see if [PascalMagick](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/PascalMagick) does the trick.